# Is there a way to get AWS Lambda's Execution Results in Airflow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, airflow, mwaa

I am using airflow to invoke lambda function using lambda hook.
I have been trying to get the lambda execution results back in airflow but unable to do so.
While checking the airflow logs, I could  see this:

{{python.py:152}} INFO- Done. Returned value was: None

Can anyone please help me with this?

I have tried using airflow xcoms but that too isn't working out.

Comment: If it is possible to show a sample code then share it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Managed Apache Airflow from AWS, in my use case upstream team was returning a small json and it was getting captured in Xcoms. Though its not recommended to pass large dataset using xcoms.

Answer (score 0):

Try a custom lambda operator which can get logs from CloudWatch: https://cevo.com.au/post/revisit-airflow-lambda-operator/

I would recommend changing `start_time = 0` to `start_time = int(time.time() * 1000)`.